# Constructing a model of ZFC in ZFC+Con(ZFC).

Tags: set-theory, model-theory

In ZFC+Con(ZFC), one can prove ZFC is consistent, so has a model. But how can I construct a model of ZFC in ZFC+Con(ZFC) formally?

I think the Con(ZFC) only says "the ZFC is consistent", not a technical statement, so if we formally construct a model of ZFC in ZFC+Con(ZFC), then there might be only axioms of ZFC  in the way of constructing the model, so it can be also constructed in ZFC.
It contradicts the Goedel's second incompleteness theorem. Therefore, we cannot formally construct a model of ZFC even in ZFC+Con(ZFC). Is this argument right?

Thank you.

Comment: The first sentence of your second paragraph makes no sense to me.  What do you mean by "not a technical statement"?  What does it mean for axioms of ZFC to be "in the way of constructing the model"?

Comment: I think Con(ZFC) seems not to be used in constructing a model of ZFC if we can construct the model in ZFC+Con(ZFC). So I wrote Con(ZFC) is not a technical statement.  I'm sorry I didnt wirte clearly.

Comment: Why do you think Con(ZFC) is not used?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, that argument isn't right. $\mathsf{ZFC}$ proves the [**completeness theorem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_completeness_theorem), and so in particular does indeed prove "$Con(\mathsf{ZFC})$ implies $\mathsf{ZFC}$ has a model."

Looking at the *proof* of the completeness theorem will demystify this: the proof actually constructs a model of the consistent theory in question, and the point is that that construction can be performed in $\mathsf{ZFC}$.

---

What this *won't* do is construct a *transitive* model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$. Indeed, the theory $$\mathsf{ZFC}+Con(\mathsf{ZFC})+\mbox{ "$\mathsf{ZFC}$ has no transitive model"}$$ is consistent (as long as $\mathsf{ZFC}+Con(\mathsf{ZFC})$ is). To see this, let $M\models\mathsf{ZFC}+Con(\mathsf{ZFC})$ and suppose $M\models$ "$\mathsf{ZFC}$ has a transitive model" (otherwise we're done). Let $\alpha$ be the least $M$-ordinal such that $M\models$ "$(L_\alpha)^M\models\mathsf{ZFC}$." Then $L_\alpha^M\models$ "$\mathsf{ZFC}$ has no transitive model" since otherwise (the $L$ of) *that* model would give us a level of $M$'s $L$-hierarchy below $\alpha$ which ($M$ thinks) is a transitive model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$.

So the models that the completeness theorem lets us construct from mere consistency are not particularly nice. But, they are models!

Comment: Thank you so much